# fluidly display horizontal list in center of wrapper div using css

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I've got the following html structure:

```
<div id = "carousel">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slides">
      <div class="upper">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
           .
           a number of li's
           .
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and the following css

```
#carousel{}
#wrapper{
    background:url("transparent.png");
}
#slides{
    margin:auto;
    width:94%;
}
.upper{
    position:relative;
}
#wrapper #slides ul{
    font-size: 0.75em;
    height: 16.2em;
    left: -2.5%;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-bottom: 2.99%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 127.9%;
}
#wrapper #slides li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    width: 13.4%;
}
```

the .upper div is accessed through jquery and it has its width and position modified.
(+1 li width, -1 li left)

problem is: although everything centers pretty good horizontally, it can't be centered vertically, also if I don't restrict the size of the ul in em's it balloons up to the size of all of its li elements

so how I can make the ul have the height of 1 li and the width of 5 of them?
also
how can I vertically center the ul in the wrapper div?
and how I can do both using only % values?

Answer (score 1):

For the vertical centering: You could set the height of the parent div however you want to the required size and then use vertical-align: middle.

As for the ul height, you could set the height of li and set the ul to have the same height.

Comment: I cant set both the width and height in %, also, if I set the height in em's or px I would have to add quite a lot of rules using @media directives in order for it to be able to scale well in however big screens